# Improper fraction to proper fraction in algebra

Tags: improper-integrals, partial-fractions

This question is in regards to the very first part of a question titled 'Express the following in partial fractions'

From my lecture notes I have got the following written down:
$$\frac{x(x+3)}{x^2+x-12}=1+\frac{2x+12}{x^2+x-12}$$

I cant understand how the numerator goes from $x(x+3)$ , to,  $1 + (2x+12)$.

I understand that the $x * x$ makes the $2x$, but how is $12$ derived from the $3$ part ?

I can do the rest of the question (factoring, cross multiply, compare numerators), just cant understand to $3$ to $12$ transition.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

-Connor

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. Please edit your question using [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It will help readability a lot.

Comment: ah nevermind, it was OP himself changing the rhs. deleting my comments.

Comment: The equals symbol between the two equations is meant to be triple bar, also the reason I cant understand it may be because perhaps the 1 is part of the numerator, please imagine it both ways as either way I still cant figure out where the 12 has come from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn polynomial long division. In this case I think it is easiest done like this (add and subtract so that you get the polynomial in the denominator also in the numerator, and then collect...)
$$
\frac{x(x+3)}{x^2+x-12}=\frac{(x^2+x-12)+(2x+12)}{x^2+x-12}=1+\frac{2x+12}{x^2+x-12}.
$$

Comment: I guess an easier way is to go building the expression from Right to Left.

Comment: Thank you, this is now beginning to make sense, I can understand that the 1 part on the left is because your dividing the left side of the equation by an identical part, however still struggling to see how the $$2x+12$$ has came to be. I'm going to learn polynomial long division right now.

Comment: @EmmadKareem Well, maybe. On the other hand, when integrating rational functions, we want to go from left to right.

Comment: @FlewittConnor The idea in the first step is that you write $x^2+3x$ as $x^2+x-12+\text{something}$. In this case that $\text{something}$ must be $2x+12$.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, after looking into and understanding the polynomial long division technique it is now clear to me. Brilliant thanks again guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Working backwards:

$$1+\frac{2x+12}{x^2+x-12}= \frac{x^2+x-12}{x^2+x-12}+\frac{2x+12}{x^2+x-12}=\frac{x^2+x-12+2x+12}{x^2+x-12}=\frac{x^2+3x}{x^2+x-12}=\frac{x(x+3)}{x^2+x-12}$$

Comment: Thank you , that definitely helps me see the bigger picture. As a side note, when looking at a question like this , how would the reader know that polynomial long division must be used before converting to partial fractions ? is it simply because you cannot execute partial fraction techniques when there are parenthesis in the numerator ?